# server not reachable by IP

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2016

I have a strange problem in our local environment. Our file server is not reachable by IP, probably since I updated it to windows server 2016. 
I can reach the server by \name and by \name.domain.local but not by \IP.

We have a local AD and DNS @ domain functional level 2012 R2.

I added a secondary network card to the server which uses DCHP instead of the fixed on the original card. But the problem is the same on that IP. All google results is about the opposite problem, IP works but not server name.

What is going on with our server/network?

Comment: Problem solved, I removed the server from the AD and re added it. In the same time I removed DFS and SMB 1. One, to me unknown, of those did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You actually *connect* the server every time with an IP, while `\\name` and `\\name.domain.local` are actually resolved using DNS or WINS before making the connection. Therefore, the most reasonable explanation would be that the IP address of your server has changed. It might for example be that your server had a static IP but during your update it has started using DHCP.

Try `nslookup name.domain.local` to get the actual IP of the server (or log in & use `ipconfig`).

Comment: Server:         ab-ad-2.trivector.local
Address:       192.168.26.212

Name:          trifile.trivector.local
Addresses:  192.168.26.203
                     192.168.27.31. Accessing both those IP with \\ip in explorer gives the error "Host unreachable"(free translation from swedish)

Answer (score 0):

> Problem solved, I removed the server from the AD and re added it. In
>   the same time I removed DFS and SMB 1. One, to me unknown, of those
>   did the trick! – niklas.unnhem Oct 23 '17 at 12:41

This action was not necessary. Next time check if Netlogon service is running. Just yesterday I did the same - upgraded 2012 to 2016 and for some freaky reason Netlogon service was disabled. Eneable it and then start it. No restart required.